# Uniform Distribution question..

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

Suppose an uniform distribution, with 0 and 80 as parameters, that explains the ‘future time of life’ of a person with age 20. Find:

1. $f_T(30)$
2. $F_T(30)$
3. $S_T(30)$
4. $μ_T(30)$

I think he meant 'a person with age 30' instead of 20. I'm not really sure where this 20 should fit.
*PS: future time of life, probably is a mistranslation, but I think you got the point

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I'd assume the 30 means that the 20 year old is expected to live 30 more years, because it says "future time of life." Regardless of whether it's a typo you should find the quantities given.

Comment: What do $f$, $F$, $S$ and $\mu$ as functions stand for? That is how are these defined?

Comment: @Math-fun f is the probability density function, F is cumulative distribution function, S is survival function and μ is the force of mortality

Comment: Thanks a lot: you first need to find the distribution of $T|T>20$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are given the future lifetime random variable $$T(20) \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,80),$$ meaning that $$\Pr[T(20) \le x] = \frac{x}{80}, \quad 0 \le x \le 80.$$

However, your question needs additional clarification.  You write for instance $f_T(30)$, but in actuarial practice, $T$ is notation for the future lifetime random variable of a newborn; i.e., $T = T(0)$.  If this is the case, we cannot answer the question because we do not have information about the probability ${}_{20} p_{0} = \Pr[T(0) > 20]$.

One alternative interpretation is that $T = T(20)$, so that for instance $f_T(30) = f_{T(20)}(30)$, the density of the future lifetime random variable evaluated at time $T(20) = 30$; i.e., at age $50$.  This of course is simply $1/80$.

However, there is yet another interpretation:  $f_T(30) = f_{T(30)}(x)$, meaning the question wants the probability density function for a life aged $30$.  This is tractable because given that the future lifetime of $(20)$ is uniform, we immediately know that $$T(30) \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,70),$$ hence $$f_{T(30)}(x) = \frac{1}{70}, \quad 0 \le x \le 70,$$ and the other functions are easily determined from this.  The reason is that given $(20)$ survives $10$ years to $(30)$, we see that $$\Pr[T(30) > x] = \Pr[T(20) > x + 10 \mid T(20) > 10] = \frac{\Pr[T(20) > x + 10]}{\Pr[T(20) > 10]}.$$  In actuarial notation, the above takes on the more familiar form $$({}_x p_{30})( {}_{10} p_{20} ) = {}_{x+10} p_{20}.$$